# Cannot use onClick in HTML/CSS template in #header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a HTML/CSS template and cannot use the onClick event inside my header. I have tried it everywhere, if I remove the `#header` class then it works just fine, so it must be something that is preventing it within the `js` I assume. I have looked in the js and I removed something called `hideOnClick`, but that did nothing so far.

I will post the JS below. I am rather poor with jquery and things like that so if it is something obvious I apologize.

```
/*
    Prologue by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @ajlkn
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
*/

(function($) {
  skel.breakpoints({
    wide: '(min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1880px)',
    normal: '(min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1620px)',
    narrow: '(min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1320px)',
    narrower: '(max-width: 960px)',
    mobile: '(max-width: 736px)'
  });

  $(function() {
    var $window = $(window),
      $body = $('body');

    // Disable animations/transitions until the page has loaded.
    $body.addClass('is-loading');

    $window.on('load', function() {
      $body.removeClass('is-loading');
    });

    // CSS polyfills (IE<9).
    if (skel.vars.IEVersion < 9) $(':last-child').addClass('last-child');

    // Fix: Placeholder polyfill.
    $('form').placeholder();

    // Prioritize "important" elements on mobile.
    skel.on('+mobile -mobile', function() {
      $.prioritize('.important\\28 mobile\\29', skel.breakpoint('mobile').active);
    });

    // Scrolly links.
    $('.scrolly').scrolly();

    // Nav.
    var $nav_a = $('#nav a');

    // Scrolly-fy links.
    $nav_a.scrolly().on('click', function(e) {
      var t = $(this),
        href = t.attr('href');

      if (href[0] != '#') return;

      e.preventDefault();

      // Clear active and lock scrollzer until scrolling has stopped
      $nav_a.removeClass('active').addClass('scrollzer-locked');

      // Set this link to active
      t.addClass('active');
    });

    // Initialize scrollzer.
    var ids = [];

    $nav_a.each(function() {
      var href = $(this).attr('href');

      if (href[0] != '#') return;

      ids.push(href.substring(1));
    });

    $.scrollzer(ids, { pad: 200, lastHack: true });

    // Header (narrower + mobile).

    // Toggle.
    $('<div id="headerToggle">' + '<a href="#header" class="toggle"></a>' + '</div>').appendTo(
      $body
    );

    // Header.
    $('#header').panel({
      delay: 500,
      // hideOnClick: true,
      hideOnSwipe: true,
      resetScroll: true,
      resetForms: true,
      side: 'left',
      target: $body,
      visibleClass: 'header-visible'
    });

    // Fix: Remove transitions on WP<10 (poor/buggy performance).
    if (skel.vars.os == 'wp' && skel.vars.osVersion < 10)
      $('#headerToggle, #header, #main').css('transition', 'none');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

example of html that wont work:

```
    <div id="header">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log('true');
        }}
      >
        Click{' '}
      </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to post your HTML as well so we can replicate your issue.

Comment: Yup -- you may be creating #header programmatically, it doesn't have the listener attached to it. Instead, try `$("body").on("click", "#header", function(){...});`

Comment: @Snowmonkey where exactly would I put that code?

Comment: Well, I got a few questions. First, why are you doing `$(window).on("load"...)` , when the `$(function(){...})` syntax won't actually run until the window has loaded and the DOM is ready? Second, where do you have your listener attached NOW?

Comment: @Snowmonkey this is a template, I haven't messed with it at all so I really do not know what any of it does , I know that is a bad idea

Comment: Not a bad idea, but you don't really need to trigger window onLoad here. it's a little redundant. Not going to BREAK, but it's sort of suspenders, belt and superglue.

Comment: Yeah, the way Vini does this below is how you need to attach listeners to dynamically added elements. For reference, this is considered event delegation (having a parent node that DOES exist, listening for events on children nodes that may or may not yet exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This WILL work because we are listening on the 'document', 
    // for a click on an element with an ID of #test-element
    $(document).on("click","#test-element",function() {
        alert("click bound to document listening for #test-element");
    });

    // This will NOT work because there is no '#test-element' ... yet
    $("#test-element").on("click",function() {
        alert("click bound directly to #test-element");
    });

    // Create the dynamic element '#test-element'
    $('body').append('<div id="test-element">Click mee</div>');
});
```

Comment: Place in inside a <script><\script> inside of <body><\body> html tag

Comment: Can I use this exactly? Or do I need to change some of the code?

Comment: your div isn't named #test-element -- this is merely an example of how event delegation works.

Comment: Replace #test-element with #header

Comment: My apologies, I’m on a cellphone right now. It’s a bit challenging to custom edit it for you at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get `click` functionality with `jQuery`:

```js
$(function()
{
    // Use the .on('click', '#id', function(){}) rather than other options
    // for binding click events to dynamically added content as pointed out
    // by @Vini
    $(document).on("click","#header",function()
    {
        alert( "Header has been clicked." );
    });

    $(document).on("click","#buttonToBeClicked",function()
    {
        alert("Button has been clicked");
    });
});
```

```css
.headerStyle
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#09f;
  text-align:center;
}

.buttonStyle
{
  position:relative;
  margin: 38px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="headerStyle">
  <input type="button" id="buttonToBeClicked" value="clickMe" class="buttonStyle" />
</div>
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And that works great, Ivan, so long as the element is loaded into the page statically. The issue, I think, is that from the OP's representative code, the #header div is being created programmatically -- so any pre-existing listeners have not been connected to it. Thus, event delegation.

Comment: You are right. In that case my jQuery is missing a couple tweeks as already seen by @Vini. I will edit to make my code true to the question.